# Angular jamine/karma test promise function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test that the promse function in the following function

```
loadDetail(id) {
    this.bookingService.getServices(id).then((ret) => {
        if (ret.result) {
            this.sevices = ret.payload;
        } 
    }).catch((error) => {});       
}
```

My test is:

```
it('loadDetail successfully return services.', inject(
    [BookingService], (service: BookingService) => {
        service.initBooking();

        let ret = new returnObj();
        ret.result = true;
        ret.payload = new Array<any>();
        ret.payload.push({id: 1, title: "Title 1"});
        ret.payload.push({id: 2, title: "Title 2"});
        ret.payload.push({id: 3, title: "Title 3"});

        const spy = spyOn(service, "getServices").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(ret));

        component.loadDetail(1);

        expect(component.sevices.length).toEqual(3);
    }
));
```

When I run the test, I get the error "Expected 0 to equal 3."
What am I doing wrong here? I've followed examples and I'm pretty sure I'm using the spy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that promises are asynchronous, and the result is asserted before `loadDetail(1)` was completed.

In order to be efficiently tested, asynchronous function should always return a promise or an observable:

```
loadDetail(id) {
  return this.bookingService.getServices(id)....
}
```

If it isn't supposed to return a result, it will be a promise of `undefined`.

This way it can be chained. This is particularly helpful with `async..await` and `async` or `fakeAsync` Angular helper:

```
it('loadDetail successfully return services.', fakeAsync(inject(
    [BookingService], async (service: BookingService) => {
        ...
        const spy = spyOn(service, "getServices").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(ret));

        await component.loadDetail(1);

        expect(component.sevices.length).toEqual(3);
    }
));
```

This can also be solved with `fakeAsync` and `tick` helpers to test asynchronous code in synchronous manner (this won't work with truly asynchronous operations like real HTTP requests):

```
it('loadDetail successfully return services.', fakeAsync(inject(
    [BookingService], (service: BookingService) => {
        ...
        const spy = spyOn(service, "getServices").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(ret));

        component.loadDetail(1);
        tick(0); // promise chain was executed

        expect(component.sevices.length).toEqual(3);
    }
));
```